# proxy package in R, can't make it work

Tags: r, function, distance

I am wanting to implement an error-weighted euclidean distance function in R (similar but not quite the same as Kumar & Patel. 2005. Rutcor Research Report. RRR 12-2005). I already know that I want to use pr_DB within proxy for this. Here is where I run into problems. The first thing I always do when looking at a new package is cut-and-paste the examples into R to see if they do what I expect them to do. This is not what happened in this case. I started with the simple included example, to wit:

```
mydist <- function(x,y) x * y
pr_DB$set_entry(FUN = mydist, names = c("test", "mydist"))
```

Okay, so far, so good. I figure, if it's going to work just like a normal "dist" type function, I'll toss in a very simple piece of data.

```
>toydat
        x           y
a -0.12817993 -1.03238513
b  1.56200731  0.93826937
c -1.24051847 -1.31005852
d -1.12892553 -1.57133401
e -1.10098308  0.06577006
```

Just a little toy set, of course. SOOOOOO, I try out the following:

```
toydist <- dist(toydat,method="mydist")
```

I get the following message:

```
Error in do.call(".External", c(list(CFUN, x, y, pairwise, if (!is.function(method)) get(method) else method),  : 
not a scalar return value
```

On a hunch, I tried out:

```
toydist <- dist(toydat,method="Euclidean")
toydist <- dist(toydat,method="Manhatten")
```

and others. They all work as expected.  I am presuming that there is something special that must be done with the basic formula for it to work in a proper manner for computing distance matrices. What I want to compute is sqrt((x<sub>i</sub> - x<sub>j</sub>)<sup>2</sup>) + (y<sub>i</sub> - y<sub>j</sub>)<sup>2</sup>) + ...(n<sub>i</sub> - n<sub>j</sub>)<sup>2</sup>) ÷ sqrt((σx<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup> + σx<sub>j</sub><sup>2</sup>) + (σy<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup> + σy<sub>j</sub><sup>2</sup>) + ...(σn<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup> + σn<sub>j</sub><sup>2</sup>)), in every pairwise combination for my data set.

I realize I could do this by spreadsheet for a single data set, but I want to do some clustering bootstrapping, which I know how to do in R. Not practical with a spreadsheet.

Comment: I know it's silly, but I think I figured it out. The trick is remembering what "scalar" vs. "vector" means. DUH! I'll post the correct solution as soon as I make sure it works.

Comment: Making the toy example work was easy. I just changed my function definition thus: `function(x,y){
xig <- (x-y)^2
sqrt(sum(xig))
}
`. Now I need to figure out how to read in the data as "points" and "errors", probably in terms of two input matrices. Any suggestions? I am not a skilled coder.

Comment: If you solved your problem, write it in an **answer**, and then after the mandatory waiting period, _accept_ it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that the requisite time has passed, I can close this out formally. The function I came up with is thus:

```
DistErrAdj <- function(x,y) {
sing.err <- sqrt((x^2) + (y^2))
sum(sing.err)
}
```